# Quick (sparse) matrix generation in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am populating a sparse matrix with some values based on a function `f` using nested for loops like so:

```
B = sparse(x, y);
for ix=1:x
    for jy=1:y
        if f(ix,jy)
              B(ix, jy) = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Is this the best and fastest way to do things in matlab, or is there an optimized way?

Comment: What's `f` ? function or matrix?

Comment: A function, sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: Can your function take vector inputs and output a vector of the same length?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following, which avoids the loops:

```
[is, js] = ind2sub(size(B), 1:numel(B));
fval = arrayfun(f, is, js);
B(find(fval)) = 1;
```

Not sure if it will be faster though.

You can skip `arrayfun` if `f` accepts vectors instead of single indices.

Comment: Do you know how I could determine which is faster?

Comment: Why don't you try both and see?

Answer (score 0):

If your function can take vector inputs, you can compute all the values of `f` in one shot and then use `sparse`:

```
[II,JJ] = ndgrid(1:y,1:x);
F = reshape(f(II(:),JJ(:)),x,y); % maybe just f(II,JJ) if f allows it
[ii,jj] = find(F);
B = sparse(ii,jj,1,x,y);
```

If your function does not take vector, you will have to run it through the loop or use `arrayfun` to generate `F(ix,iy) = f(ix,iy);`, then use `find` and `sparse` as above.

Comment: It's a little hard to nail this down without the function `f`, especially since `x` is rows and `y` is columns in the question. Some fiddling with indexes may be needed, but the point is to use `sparse` once you compute `F`...